# Редактор кода для perl

Tags: perl, active-perl

Какой редактор кода посоветуете для языка perl? Пока нашел только один рабочий, это Perl Express 2.4.5, но интерфейс мне совершенно не понравился. Больше ничего достойного найти не могу.

Comment: visual studio code с плагинами пробовали? sublime, vim, emacs. И даже у Idea есть плагин, который пытается работать с перлом. Ещё есть Padre, но он похоже заброшен

Comment: в visual не пробовал, та и мне чисто для perl нужно, поэтому не хочу качать visual

Comment: visual studio code это не visual studio.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Редакторов много. Главное понять, что от них хочется.

Если просто редактировать текст+подсветка:

- vim/gvim - удобно, если один скрипт поправить. нагенерировав ctags, можно даже использовать на больших проектах.
- nano (Linux) - для любителей.
- emacs - для ценителей.
- sublime - мне нравится, если поднастроить - красиво. Минус - немного платно. И вроде перловый плагин плохо работает под виндой, но подсветка синтаксиса и шрифты - хорошо.
- visual studio code/atom.

чуточку побольше:

- [padre](http://padre.perlide.org/) - пытается быть прям IDE, но давно-давно не обновлялась (2013). Выглядит сильно олдскульно.
- IDEA + [perl плагин](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7796-perl), [хвалебные оды](https://habr.com/ru/post/265799/).
- [visual studio code](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) + perl плагин. Их там много, но лучше выбрать тот, который поддерживает Language server (aka LSP). Мне кажется, этот будет хорош [richterger.perl](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=richterger.perl). Ещё один плюс - прозрачная работа через ssh, может оказаться суперудобно (мне очень нравится)
- [Komodo](https://www.activestate.com/products/komodo-ide/perl-editor/) - очень хвалят, но я его смотрел очень-очень давно, а сейчас по скриншотам он совсем другой.

Comment: а какие из этих редакторов могут компилировать код ?

Comment: компилить? перловый код? Или просто запустить/проверить на ошибки?

Comment: ну да, запустить

Comment: любой. Просто в виме придется чуточку поднастроить, в других скорее всего прям с коробки

Answer (score 0):

Я использую visual studio code или пхп шторм. Все с плагинами.