# Установка языка Perl В linux 2022

Tags: linux, администрирование, perl, скрипт, автоматизация

Здравствуйте начал изучать язык программирования Perl, работаю в Gnu/linux - Debian/Ubuntu. По умолчанию стоит версия Perl-5.30.0

Устанавливал через Perlbrew последнюю версию, официальная документация: (https://metacpan.org/pod/App::perlbrew)

Perl работает, но после перезагрузки опять системная версия.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно устанавливать Perl, чтобы версию не настаивать каждый раз. Я понимаю, что Perlvrew это не совсем то, я пробовал через Perl source code:
(https://www.cpan.org/src/README.html)

Перл устанавливается, но перезагрузка и опять дефолтная версия. Еще одна проблема это примерно 40 минут ожидания, когда установится язык из исходного кода, когда вводил "make test" - выдавало ошибку об ненайденном каталоге, как в этой ситуации поступать я пока не знаю.

В общем нужна инструкция от программистов, системных администраторов, которые работают в UNIX системах и имеют дело с Perl5. Основные вопросы:

1,2,3 вопрос для меня самые важные...

1. Как правильно установить версию Perl, чтобы работать с нужной версией?
2. В какую папку сохранять (bin,etc) или что посоветуйте?
3. Есть ли возможность сохранить заготовку пути к нужной версии перла (#!/usr/bin/perl)?
4. Посоветуйте бесплатное простое ide для Linux. Работаю  в Geany и установил Notepad, Vscode на VirtualBox тормозит. Если есть что - то годное дайте пожалуйста рекомендацию.
5. Если есть возможность дайте информацию с задачами по Perl и возможными решениями, а также по работе в linux/Perl.

Спасибо всем, кто поможет с ответом.

Всем добра!

Comment: Подозреваю, вы в инструкции perlbrew упустили один очень важный пункт «You then need to include a bashrc/cshrc provided by perlbrew to tweak the PATH for you.»

Comment: @MetH92 - а зачем устанавливать себе версию через Brew?

Answer (score 1):

Пройдем по пунктам.

1. Я более, чем уверен, что Вам не нужен самый последний перл. Ну вот не нужен. 5.30 точно хватит для обучения. Даже 5.16. Поэтому, правильный способ установить перл - использовать системный. Посмотрел на своих машинках - на убунте 5.32 системный, на генту - 5.34. Последний официальный - 5.34.1. Если у Вас убунта - обновитесь просто.
2. `В какую папку сохранять` - это очень интересный вопрос. В Линукс принято файлики аккуратно раскладывать по каталогам (папка - это более виндовое название). В /etc обычно помещаются всякие конфиги, в /bin - системноважные бинарники. В разных дистрибутивах могут быть свои правила. Если Вы устанавливаете свою версию Perl, то не нужно им засорять систему. Поэтому, обычно такое устанавливают либо в свой домашний каталог в отдельную папку, либо в /opt. В системные каталоги (/etc, /bin, /usr/bin и подобные устанавливайте только если очень хорошо понимаете, что делаете. Если Вы только начали учится - не делайте так).
3. Оно для этого и задумывалось. Но если у Вас самособранный перл, то ему нужно будет ещё указать, где его библиотеки, где его конфиги и не факт, что оно просто так взлетит. Но попробовать можно.
4. Я уже когда то отвечал на этот вопрос - [Редактор кода для perl](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1230274/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-perl) . Я сейчас персонально использую vim/nvim + tmux. Мне хватает. Некоторые говорят, что vim не IDE, но это их проблемы.
5. Возьмите любой сайт с задачками (https://leetcode.com, https://projecteuler.net/) и просто начните решать простые задачи. Таким образом Вы научитесь работать с простыми вещами типа массивов, вызовов функций.  Такие знания кажутся простыми, но как только доходит до практики....
   Также рекомендую вот такой сайт - http://pragmaticperl.com/ там целая серия журнала о Perl, там точно будут интересные статьи.

Answer (score 0):

1. Уверен, что для знакомства хватит системного Perl с головой. На этом этапе нет никакого смысла заморачиваться с сборкой. Так-то вы сделали всё верно, выбрали `perlbrew`.
2. Однозначно, собирать свою версию следует в `/opt`.
3. После шебанга стоит писать что-то вроде `#!/usr/bin/env perl`, тогда не придётся завязываться на жесткие пути.
4. Есть хороший плагин для IDE от Jetbrains, подходит для любого (Clion/PyCharm/etc). Наверное, можно даже запустить для Community-версий. Рекомендую.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ @Кирилл Новгородцев, Perlbrew выбрал из - за сходства с RVM (Ruby), не совсем понимаю о системном Perl (используй его и все будет хорошо), обычно стараются использовать обкатанную версию (дорелизную), свежий perl нужен для просмотра новых возможностей, интересна новая ветка Perl7-0.0. Я знаю что в нем ничего не измениться кроме настроек со  старта, вот и пробую установить perl как виртуальный, чтобы работать с нужной версией. (Так как с языком Ruby). Буду пробовать Perlbrew, если ничего другого нет. Благодарю за ответ.